# Why is MySQL auto_increment skipping numbers

Tags: mysql, database, import, autocomplete, mysqlimport

We are running an import of an existing product table into a new table of our own. The import script we've written runs perfectly and inserts the right amount of rows (6000 or so). However, after the import the next auto incremented primary key/id is 1500 entries (or so) above the number of rows in the table.

We can't understand why MySQL is doing this and we'd like it to stop. I've done the usual searches online looking for help but I am drawing a blank - any ideas?

Comment: Are you inserting any data into auto-incrementing column?

Comment: No. We're leaving the auto-incremener do it's 'thing'.

Comment: I've experienced the same when I run `insert into tb select * from tb1;` and `insert into tb values() for 1 row`. The last insert skips the auto_increment field by over 6000. Hard to believe.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this simple table for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

And import file that look like:

```
"id","name"
1,"product 1"
2,"product 2"
5,"product 3"
102,"product 4"
```

Then you are importing data to both columns, so auto incrementing mechanism does not work.
After importing all rows, autoincrement value for table is set to **MAX(id)+1** [*103* in this case] to ensure next autoincremented id is unique. If it was equal to number of rows inserted, then next autincrement value would be 5 and would colide with row #3.

If you want to have clean start and last id equal to number of rows you have to either get rid of "id" column from **.csv** file, or create table **without AUTO_INCREMENT** for **id**, import data and run this simple sql:

```
SET @i=0;
UPDATE `products` SET id=@i:=@i+1 ORDER BY id;
ALTER TABLE `products`  CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

First query sets auxiliary variable, that will be incremented before updating the record.
Second one updates record to have id equal to row number.
Third will change id column to be autoincremented and set proper value for next autoindex.

But before changing any primary keys ensure that they are not used in any other tables as foreign keys!

Comment: +1 for a great answer but that isn't what the problem is. We run the import and create our own, auto incremental primary key. The import brings in 6000(or so records) with sequential IDs. The next auto ID should then be 6001 but what we are getting instead is 7500 (say).

Comment: If so, then only thing that comes to mind, is to check if they are really sequential - have you tried `SELECT MAX(id) FROM products` after importing data or `ALTER TABLE products ORDER BY id` and see if the last rows have predicted values?

Answer (score 0):

If you perform this command:

```
show create table Foo
```

Then you will see what the `AUTO_INCREMENT=` is set too. 

My guess is that it is not set to start with 0.

You should then create your new table to have the AUTO_INCREMENT set to 0 (or 1, I cannot remember from the top of my head). This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion but AUTO_INCREMENT is set to 1 and works a treat other than right after the large import.